# dart removeWhere() - where does the data go?

Tags: dart

I am trying to write a function in dart that takes a string that has some words that be begin with a "#" character and split it into two sets. One that contains string with only the "#" character and one with no "#" characters.

There are some obvious ways i could do this with a for loop, but want to use these fancy list processing functions (what are these called exactly?) like where() forEach().

so here is my attempt.

```dart
void main() {
    String inputText = "Hello world. #hithere";
    inputText.split(" ").where((element) => element.startsWith("#"))
    .forEach((item) {
      print(item);
    });
    inputText.split(" ").removeWhere((element) => element.startsWith("#"));    
    print(inputText);   
}
```

Here is the output of the program:

**#hithere**

**Hello world. #hithere**

the first part works as expected, but the second part i expected the removeWhere would remove the element #hithere from my list....

but this this didnt happen.

So my question is this. Did the removeWhere() method remove this element correctly? If so where is the list that has this element removed? How do i get access to it?

my explanation of what happend is that the split(" ") method created a List and the removeWhere() method operated on this List and removed the element i told it to... but what i dont understand is how i can get access to this list? where does this list exist?

what i was think i should do is something like this:

```
inputText.split(" ").removeWhere((element) => element.startsWith("#")).join();
```

I was hoping that i could take the List with the removed elements and join() them back into a string... but since the removeWhere() method returns void.. i have no idea where the list that has removed elements exists?

Comment: As far as I can tell, `split()` returns a list, from which you remove the items. Since the result from `split()` is never stored anywhere, you'll never see the result.

Comment: yes ```split()``` does return a list that i can remove the items from.. and i would like to use removeWhere() to remove the item.. i am very confused on where the list that has the removed items goes..

Comment: It goes nowhere (aka, will be garbage collected real soon now) because you don't store any reference to it anywhere. Try `var newText = inputText.split(" ").removeWhere((element) => element.startsWith("#")).join(); print(newText);.

Comment: that doesnt work... i get " Error: The method 'join' isn't defined for the class 'void'."

Comment: Since `removeWhere` confusingly enough does not return anything but modifies the list you pass in, I think he means something like `var oldTextSplit = inputText.split(" "); oldTextSplit.removeWhere((element) => element.startsWith("#")); var newText = oldTextSplit.join()`

Comment: yes that works. so i guess i have to capture the list in a variable then call removeWhere on the list. This is a little confusing. it would seem to make more sense to me if removeWhere explicitly return the list  it modified rather than implicit modifying the list you pass in. this way you can chain things togethor and not have to save a extra variable..

Comment: @user254340 I completely agree :)

Comment: var newList = aString.split(' ')..removeWhere(.....).  Notice the cascade call, which permits the updated list to pass through to newList, not the result of removeWhere.